# How to prevent focusing Controls in UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, focus, tabstop

I have a `User-Control` with 2 `Textbox` and 1 `Button`, Something like below:

[image: my UserControl]

When I press the button a form show and when the form closed I want to leave focus from `User-Control` and next control on the `Form` got focus, I write this code for this issue:

```
private void Btn_Select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (t.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        ProcessTabKey(true);
}
```

I excepted that next control on the Parent Form got focus BUT the textbox on `UserControl` got focus, I change the `TabStop` property to `false` for 2 `textbox` but still have the problem.

Could anyone know how I solve this problem?

Comment: UserControl.ProcessTabKey() just doesn't do what you hope it does.  You'll have better odds with  this.FindForm().SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);  The only truly correct way is to leave it up to the form to decide which control should get the focus next, raise an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
this.FindForm().SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
```

Instead Of:

```
UserControl.ProcessTabKey();
```

Will Solve Problem.